# IRR(Internal Rate of Return) UDF in TeraData

Tags: c, arrays, teradata

i'm trying to create a UDF for [IRR](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/irr.asp) in Teradata.

I want store all the elements of row in my intermediate storage in the form of array(appending one at a time).This help me to use the elements multiple times(going with trial and error logic)

I just want to know, which is the compatible data type to use in "typedef" for this requirement in teradata?

As IRR logic is some what lengthy, im representing my problem here with the help of a new sum_redefined function.

Im just trying to calculate sum the passed arguments(row elements) by storing them into a array and adding them afterwards.

Here is my code:

Note: The below is obviously wont compile because i'm still trying to understand the correct data type in Teradata for C Arrays.

```
#define SQL_TEXT Latin_Text
#include <sqltypes_td.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
typedef struct agr_storage {
        int count;
        ARRAY_HANDLE elements[100];
} AGR_Storage;

void SUM_REDEFINED( FNC_Phase phase,
              FNC_Context_t *fctx,
              FLOAT *x, //here im passing row element one by one
              FLOAT *result,
              int *x_i,
              int *result_i,
              char sqlstate[6],
              SQL_TEXT fncname[129],
              SQL_TEXT sfncname[129],
              SQL_TEXT error_message[257] )
{

     AGR_Storage *s1 = fctx->interim1;

     switch (phase)
     {

     case AGR_INIT:
     s1 = FNC_DefMem(sizeof(AGR_Storage));
     if (s1 == NULL)
     {
        strcpy(sqlstate, "U0001");
        return;
     }
     s1->count = 0;
     s1->elements[100]={0};

     case AGR_DETAIL:
     if (*x_i != -1)
     {
     s1->count++;
     s1->elemnts[s1->count]=*x;//appending elemts one by one

     break;

     case AGR_COMBINE:


     case AGR_FINAL:
     {
        int no_of_elements=s1->count;
        int i=0;
        FLOAT sum=0;
        for(i=0;i<no_of_elements;i++){
                sum+=s1->elements[i];    //adding all the elements
                }

     *result = sum;  //returning the sum
     break;
     }

     case AGR_NODATA:
          *result_i = -1;
          break;

     default:
             /* If it gets here there must be an error because this */
             /* function does not accept any other phase options */
             strcpy(sqlstate, "U0005");
     }
     return;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any sample code for what you have tried thus far?

Comment: @RobPaller i updated question with my problem..Please let me know if you require any more details

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can declare arrays in Teradata as we do in C. But please keep in mind that for UDF each intermediate storage block space is limited to 64 bytes.so if you are defining an integer array you cant make array larger than 16 integers(integer takes 4 bytes 16*4=64). Same goes with other datatypes as well.

So change your code to

```
typedef struct agr_storage {
        int count;
        int elements[*Number here*];
} AGR_Storage;
```

The cumulative sum of all the declared datatypes should be less than 64 bytes.

Comment: The size of an *intermediate storage block* is limited to 64000 bytes and not 64 byte: http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_15_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1147_151K/C_UDFs.045.073.html